# WPF - remove application auto run after startup

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

So i using this code to add `Key registry`  to automatically open my application on startup:

```
Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey key = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run", true);
Assembly curAssembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
key.SetValue(curAssembly.GetName().Name, curAssembly.Location);
```

So now i want to be able to remove this option in order to add this to m application user define so i search for `RemoveKey` on something similar.

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the [DeleteValue()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dk8b3th2.aspx) method:

```
key.DeleteValue(curAssembly.GetName().Name);
```